# Teams shows badge number for notification about a message that I am currently viewing in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I do not understand how the badge count in Microsoft teams work.

I am getting this taskbar icon appearance

[image]

even if the chat window that has the new message (showing in bold) is open already (I can read the message).

Why isnt the notification count reset?

I have to go forth and back between tabs before I get the green tick icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks that Microsoft Teams in your computer is only able to notice some of your actions.

---

Some web browsers constrain web apps to what happen on their window and the windows that they open. Some web apps might override these restrictions by using web browser extensions and using mechanism to interact with the user computer i.e. by displaying notifications or commucating with installable software.

Windows users and users that installed Office 365 or other Microsoft software might have on their computers utilities that might interact with Microsoft Teams.

Notes:

- By window I'm refering to a web browser window or tab.
- I'm not an active users of Microsoft Teams